# convert into a single row matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix say `a = [1 5 9;7 8 5; 7 1 4];`

I want to make a linear matrix of `a` i.e., `a1 = [1 5 9 7 8 5 7 1 4];`

Answer (score 4):

```
a'(:)' %# Octave
b= a'; b(:)' %# Matlab
```

For more information on [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) and on [colon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html).

**Added**, more verbose variations may be occasionally practical as well:

```
a'(ind2sub([3 3], 1: 9))
permute(a, [2 1])(ind2sub([3 3], 1: 9))
```

Here `permute(a, [2 1])` is now equivalent to `a.'`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it in Matlab

```
a1 = a(:);
```

Or if you need to go by rows, transpose it before and after:

```
b = a';
b1 = b(:);
a1 = b1';
```

Answer (score 1):

One more variant

```
a = reshape( a.', 1, numel(a) )
```

Note use of `.'` to get the non-conjugated [TRANSPOSE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/transpose.html) - `'` corresponds to [CTRANSPOSE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ctranspose.html)

Comment: FWIW, for real matrices `'` boils just down to be `.'`. I think the usage of `'` is very common and it keeps your code more readable. Thanks